# Play framework how to gracefully handle empty body

Tags: playframework

It may seem that the request body class provides no api (?) for checking whether any body is supplied by the caller or not, at least when using [the routing DSL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSirdRouter). If e.g. expecting JSON, It could have been nice to:

```
  case PATCH(p"/foo") => Action { request =>
      val body: Option[JsValue] = request.body.asJson
      body match {
        case None =>
          Results.NoContent
        case Some(body) =>
          Results.Ok(s"got post request with body of length ${body.toString.length}")
      }
    }
  }
```

But `Results.NoContent` will never be reached and a "bad request" response is sent to the client following an exception `Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input...`. Would be nice to know how the http "no content" response can be sent for such a case that caller did not include a body. I could think of first converting to text, only then to Json as a workaround. Any cleaner way? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use validate function that return JsScuccess or JsError.

```
 implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[ContractorRequest] match {
      case s: JsSuccess[ContractorRequest] =>
        val contractor = Contractor.fromRequest(s.get)
        contractorsService.update(contractor).map { contractor =>
          Ok(Json.toJson(contractor))
        }
      case e: JsError =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.toJson(ErrorWrapper("invalidJson", JsError.toJson(e).toString))))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question: You must implement the check of an empty body by yourself. Regarding the code there shouldn't be sent a 400 automatically.

You can specify the requests content type to be json via body parser as argument to `Action` or `Action.async`.
Additionally the case class to desereialize the JSON to can be specified at the body parser via type parameter.

```scala
case class Foo(bar: String)
object Foo {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Foo]
}

...

case PATCH(p"/foo") => Action(parse.json[Foo]) { request =>
  val foo = request.body
  Ok(s"got valid request with $foo")
}
```

This handles requests with invalid JSON payloads by responding with `BadRequest`

Empty body requests are invalid and should be responded with `BadRequest`.
You find the docs here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.DefaultPlayBodyParsers